# How can I upload files in a Google Drive folder to Dropbox

Tags: google-drive, dropbox, if-this-then-that

I'm creating a system for myself that uses cloud storage and symbolic links to sync my Minecraft worlds between computers. Although my primary service is Google Drive, I have had to utilize Dropbox to store files on the one Linux computer I play on. As such, I've set up an IFTTT recipe that syncs Dropbox saves with Google Drive, but due to Drive not having an New File In Drive trigger, I cannot vice versa this with IFTTT. What are some other ways I could sync just the one folder in Dropbox with Google Drive?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just go Dropbox for this solution on all the other computers? I use Drive, Dropbox, and OneDrive on the same systems without issue.

Answer (score -1):

There are various tools to [sync files between cloud services](https://www.google.com/search?q=sync%20files%20between%20cloud%20services).

Also a Google Apps script might be able to do this for you.